# Exact Number of weeks with decimals calculated in SET of a DECLAREd variable

Tags: sql-server

I need values in my declared variable to contain 3 decimal places to reflect exact (non integer) number of weeks in a month.

However, SET variables return INT values with anything I tried: CONVERT, CAST or various data types.

I paste script below. I could only come up with a workaround: multiply by 1000 in SET only to divide in the select statement.

But I want to avoid calculated ("Calc8d" below) values in SELECT, SETting them as variables instead. So I wonder:

(1) is my 'data type' or 'SELECT' within 'SET' wrong? 
(2) Or does a variable never return decimal places but only integers? A straight calculation DECALREd as DECIMAL of 31/7 still returns 4 not 4.428571 or similar. (but DATE and DATETIME are non-integers, or are they?).

It's a shame that months and years are not metric, decimal or even septadecimal so split weeks at beginning or EOM split weeks are always an issue for Monthly like-for -like or other "Monthly" KPI type of reports... >:-P

```
    DECLARE @ExactNoOfWeeks_LastMowCONV DECIMAL SET @ExactNoOfWeeks_LastMowCONV = ROUND(CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2),DATEPART(d,EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)))/7,3)
DECLARE @ExactNoOfWeeks_LastMowCAST DECIMAL SET @ExactNoOfWeeks_LastMowCAST = ROUND(CAST(DATEPART(d,EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)) AS FLOAT)/7,3)
DECLARE @ExactNoOfWeeks_LastMonth3K DECIMAL SET @ExactNoOfWeeks_LastMonth3K = ROUND(CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2),DATEPART(d,EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)))/7,3) * 1000
DECLARE @StraightCalc DECIMAL SET @StraightCalc = 31/7

SELECT
DATEPART(d,EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)) 'Days Prev Mo' -- number of days in pervious month
,DATEPART(d,EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1))/7 'Calc8d (w/o CAST)' -- same as above devided by nr of days in a week
,ROUND(CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2),DATEPART(d,EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)))/7,8) 'Calc8d (w/CONVERT)' -- calculated with CONVERT
,ROUND(CAST(DATEPART(d,EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)) AS FLOAT)/7,3) 'Calc8d (w/CAST)' -- calculated with CAST
,@ExactNoOfWeeks_LastMowCONV 'Var(w/CONVERT)' -- SELECTed Variable SET with same calculation as above returns an integer
,@ExactNoOfWeeks_LastMowCAST 'Var(w/CAST)' -- idem
,@ExactNoOfWeeks_LastMonth3K/1000 'Var/1K' -- idem
,@StraightCalc 'Var Straight Calc' -- idem
,CONVERT(NVARCHAR,GETDATE(),103) 'Today'
,CONVERT(NVARCHAR,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1),103) 'Last EOM'


Days Prev Mo       31
Calc8d (w/o CAST)   4
Calc8d (w/CONVERT)  4.428571
Calc8d (w/CAST)    4.429
Var(w/CONVERT)     4
Var(w/CAST)        4
Var/1K              4.429
Var Straight Calc   4
Today                06/11/15
Last EOM              31/10/15
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrRIB.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the precision and scale. [The default scale is zero.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms187746(v=sql.105).aspx)

This works:

```
DECLARE @ExactNoOfWeeks_LastMowCONV DECIMAL(4,3)
SET @ExactNoOfWeeks_LastMowCONV = 1.145
select @ExactNoOfWeeks_LastMowCONV
```

Output: **1.145**

This doesn't:

```
DECLARE @ExactNoOfWeeks_LastMowCONV DECIMAL
SET @ExactNoOfWeeks_LastMowCONV = 1.145
select @ExactNoOfWeeks_LastMowCONV
```

Output: **1**